# sub tilde in latex

Tags: latex, tilde

in latex with \tilde{x} put ~ over x.
how I can put ~ down x ?

Answer (score 4):

The command `\underset` may help. [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) would be another good place to ask, it's specialized in TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: An answer, using the undertilde package, has been given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2329/sub-tilde-in-latex